# Start WSL in a directory from mapped WSL drive

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have mapped WSL drive as a network drive (`\\wsl$\Ubuntu\`) to drive Z:\ on Windows. I would like to be able to browse this drive in Windows' explorer and then  use option "Open Linux shell here" as well as use a path on drive Z:\ to open a WSL terminal in IDE such as Intellij. However, when I try to do this, the terminal opens in my home directory `~`. This does not happen when I do this on drive C:\ .

How can I configure WSL so that it can start in directories under Z:\ mapped drive?

Comment: `Z:` is as same as Ubuntu root directory `/`, so you can access Ubuntu without mapping it as a drive. The mapping requires for Windows programs to access WSL distribution files.

Comment: I can access a directory on disk Z manually, as it is mapped to `/`, but I need the ability to open start a WSL's bash in a directory on disk Z:, the same as when starting WSL from a directory on C:

Comment: Just add `cd /path/to/folder` command in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` etc.

Comment: It will move me to the directory every time I open WSL, even when I open it in a different directory

Comment: Try this command `wsl.exe sh -c "cd /path/to/folder; bash"`.

Comment: It works in regular terminal, but for some reason it doesn't work when starting an Intellij terminal: `sh: 1: /home/hyster/Workspace: Permission denied`